# How to use 'i.e.' in a sentence?

Tags: usage, punctuation, latin

Which of the following ways of using ***i.e.*** in a sentence is correct?

> 1) The elephant is a pachyderm, i.e., an animal with thick skin and nails resembling hooves.
>   2) The elephant is a pachyderm (i.e., an animal with thick skin and nails resembling hooves).

Also, if we use ***i.e.*** as in the first sentence, should we use a comma before it?

Comment: A modern way to use "i.e." is to use it without periods and italicize it, i.e., *ie*. One way to clean things up is to get rid of unncessary periods. And I think that because fewer people realize that "i.e." comes from an abbreviation in Latin that *ie* is now used (by those in the know) as a sort of term, or even a symbol, for "that is" that doesn't necessarily hearken back to the Latin words. The same for *eg* (for example). Of course, one still has to know what the English words are, or at least to use one and when the other--which is another thing many writers fumble at.

Answer (score 3):

First question: The *i.e.*, which means "*that is*", is unnecessary in both sentences. It's clear from context that "*an animal with thick skin and nails resembling hooves*" is a definition of "*pachyderm*". However, it isn't necessarily incorrect, just verbose.

Second question: Yes, the comma is necessary, but style manuals don't all agree on whether the second comma is required. Some publishers don't require it, some do, and some forbid it.

Third question: "When should I use ***i.e.***? Answer: When it isn't clear that what follows is in apposition. Two good examples of when ***i.e.*** is useful:

> "[He did not respond, i.e., he declined](http://www.jpschoemer.com/MostCommonErrors.html)".
>   "[Eating squirrel taco without any ranch dressing is like playing leapfrog with a unicorn, i.e., a very bad idea.](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/ie)"

In both sentences immediately above, it's not as clear as in your two sentences that the final phrase is apposite to the initial clause, especially in the second example: What exactly does "a bad idea" refer to?

Rule of thumb: Avoid these Latin abbreviations whenever possible if they seem superfluous. Always avoid unnecessary words.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining how and when we should use i.e :) . When do we use i.e within parenthesis ?

Comment: Using parentheses is a style choice. Unless your prescribed style manual tells you when to & not to use parenthetical remarks, it's up to you. A good rule of thumb is to avoid using them too often: they clutter up a page. You can see this very (very (very (very))) clearly on any page in a paper that uses the inane _[APA Style Guide](http://www.apastyle.org/learn/faqs/references-in-parentheses.aspx)_, which requires all reference citations to be enclosed in parentheses.